# how to shift non nan value in multiple columns row wise by group?

Tags: python, pandas, shift

so i have data frame as below

| A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 | A6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | nan | 3 | 7 | nan | 8 |
| nan | 5 | nan | 11 | 9 | nan |
| 54 | 6 | 84 | 12 | 3 | nan |
| 10 | nan | nan | 16 | nan | 45 |
| 12 | 93 | 13 | 31 | 5 | 91 |
| 73 | nan | 45 | nan | nan | 9 |

i want to shift the whole data frame n rows such that it skips nan rows but still preserve it.
desire output:
for n =2

| A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 | A6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| nan | nan | nan | 7 | nan | nan |
| 1 | nan | nan | 11 | nan | nan |
| 54 | 5 | 3 | 12 | 9 | 8 |
| 10 | nan | 84 | nan | nan | 45 |

i tried the following:

```
df['dummy'] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if pd.notnull(x[column]) else 0, axis=1)
df['dummy2'] = df.groupby(['dummy'])[column].shift(n)
df[column] = df.apply(lambda x: x['dummy2'] if x['dummy']==1 else x[column], axis=1)
```

which is good if there is only a few columns i need to shift.

i also tried the applymap function

```
dummy_df = df.applymap(lambda x: 1 if pd.notnull(x) else 0)
```

which returns a dummy data frame to separate groups that i want to shift, just have no idea what to do next with it.
the problem is that there are thousands of columns i need to shift row wise.

Is there any ways i can do this using minimum loops? And are there any ways to do it with groupby function using dummy_df?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lambda function with [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) and [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().shift(2))

print (df)
     A1   A2    A3    A4   A5    A6
0   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN
1   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN
2   NaN  NaN   NaN   7.0  NaN   NaN
3   1.0  NaN   NaN  11.0  NaN   NaN
4  54.0  5.0   3.0  12.0  9.0   8.0
5  10.0  NaN  84.0   NaN  NaN  45.0
```

Comment: Wow, seems you solve it just using one line of code. i have been spend days to solve it and still cannot solve that without using loops.

Comment: just another question if there were values in those NaN cells, and i want to shift n rows with repect to those NaN cells, is there any way to do it? say Nan cells contain cats' name while non-nan cells contain dogs' name, and i want to shift all of them n rows with repect to their group.

Comment: @beginer101 - how possible distinguish between cats and dogs names?

Comment: for example if the value of a cell meets specific condition it is in cat group (eg. positive and even intergers), and if it meets other condition it is in dog group(eg. nagative odd intergers). of course there can be more groups, just that i want to solve easier questions first before going into too much as it is easier to look where i do wrong in my code. And thanks a lot with df = df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().shift(2)) solution, i never though of using shift in lambda function, it helps a lot that i do not need to shift each column separately.

Comment: @beginer101 - E.g do you need `df = df.apply(lambda x: x[x > 0].shift(2))` ? If shifting without positive values? in another words, positive values are processing like `NaN`s by `df = df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().shift(2))`

Comment: Wow, seems that is the solution......  i dont know what to say, how do you people do this with just doing slight change of code.... i just dont know what to say. there is a lot that i need to learn....

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
tmp = df.apply(
    lambda s: s.sort_values(
        key=lambda v: pd.notnull(v)
        ).values
    )
res = tmp.shift(2)
res
```

Comment: i did not think of using lambda inside lambda before, nice trick and i need more time to figure out using it. But i am not trying to sort value to the bottom of data frame, cells with nan value still perserve nan value while cells are non-nan get nan-non values  from previous nth cells. Let me change the table to make the question clearer.